# When I try to destructure my state object in react typescript, I get an `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, react-typescript

When I try to destructure my state object in react typescript, I get an `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error. If I use optional chaining I got this error `const newUser: NewUser | undefined Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

**The error is showing when I am trying to destructure object** `RegisterUser(newUser?.email, newUser?.password, newUser?.name, navigate)`

My Code:

```
type NewUser ={
    name: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    navigate: string
}


const Register = () => {
    const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState<NewUser>() // single object will return
  
    const [RegisterUser] = UseFirebase()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const handleValues = (e: any) => {
        const field = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value
        const user: any = { ...newUser }
        user[field] = value
        setNewUser(user)

    }

    const handleRegister = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // ERROR
        RegisterUser(newUser.email, newUser.password, newUser.name, navigate)
        // console.log('user name', newUser.name, newUser.email, newUser.password);
    }
.......
```

Could someone please tell me what type of mistake I made?

Comment: There has to be a good original question to point to for this. The reason is that on the first render, `newUser` is `undefined`, because you haven't specified any initial value for it in `useState`.

Comment: Side note: That's not *destructuring*, that's just property access.

Comment: Your question shows two very different things, `RegisterUser(newUser?.email, newUser?.password, newUser?.name, navigate)` in the text, and `RegisterUser(newUser.email, newUser.password, newUser.name, navigate)` in the actual code. The former won't give you the error you describe, because you're using optional chaining. The latter, in the code, will.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well that the typescript for yaa, you need to check first that you will not get undefined as a value by simply doing condition check like this

```
const handleRegister = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (newUser?.email && newUser?.password && newUser?.name) {
        RegisterUser(newUser.email, newUser.password, newUser.name, navigate)
        } else { 
// show some error handling here or error to user that he didnt enter value etc
 }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your object is not undefined, you should try

```
   RegisterUser(newUser!.email, newUser!.password, newUser!.name, navigate)
```

Comment: The issue in the question is that `newUser`, itself, is `undefined`, not an issue with its properties being `undefined`.

Comment: I missed that, In that case if it is sure that value is not undefined you should try:-                   
 ````RegisterUser(newUser!.email, newUser!.password, newUser!.name, navigate)````